# Redireccion a url copiada despues de login google en php

Tags: php, login, google-api

resulta que tengo el sitio ej: misitio.com que usa un login atraves de google en ej:misitio.com/login.php, cuando el usuario se loguea es redirigido a ej:misitio.com/index.php, el problema sucede cuando se vence o no inicia la sesión y el usuario copia y pega por ej el link: misitio.com/facturas.php, pasa que es redirigido a ej:misitio.com/login.php y cuando se logea se redirige al index.php.

Me gustaría que cuando el usuario copie y pegue el link, sea redirigido al mismo link que copio y no al index, tengo en mi Config.php el siguiente código.

```
  $client_id = 'xxxxxx';
  $client_secret ='xxxxx';
  $redirect_uri = 'https://www.misitio.com/';

  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setClientId($client_id);
  $client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
  $client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
  $client->addScope("email");
  $client->addScope("profile");
```

Comment: Alguna sugerencia sería. 1º O creas una cookie o algún valor que detecte la última página que estubo el cliente o 2º Sin cambiar de fichero haces el login haciendo un if con un include de si no esta logeado

Comment: creo q la primera sugerencia es mas sencillo voy a intentarlo asi gracicas